# Saving image of every python execution in a folder with a serial number as file name

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and would like to execute a code which saves an image into particular directory.
The thing is, I would like to save image with a serial number so that I can have many images(each execution gives one image) in the directory.

```
    plt.savefig('Images/Imageplot.png') ## Image saved to particular folder
```

Answer (score 0):

About the serial number, you can use the uuid library to generate a random and unique id for an image. See more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-random-ids-using-uuid-python/

To save images, it is a bit more complicated. It requires you to import the os library.

Here is an example:

```
import os

UPLOADED_FILE_DIR_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static", "uploaded-images")

my_file_path = os.path.join(UPLOADED_FILE_DIR_PATH, my_filename)
image_file.save(my_file_path)
```

This is a block of code I used previously for my website, so it may not apply for you, depending on your situation. I personnaly like that method, but if you are unsatisfied, take a look at this for more options: https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-and-saving-images-in-python-ba5a1f5058fb